# How does this result follow?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

In my real analysis text, an example of proof by induction is given by proving that for any real $x\ge 0$ and all integers $n\ge 0$ $$(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx+\frac {n(n-1)}2x^2$$

I can follow and understand the proof but then the next line after the proof is

> It follows that $$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$$ and $$(1+x)^n \gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$ hold for every nonnegative ...

How do these stricter results follow from the above?  Wouldn't I need to do a proof by induction for each of these also?

Comment: the first follows by subtracting a non-negative term from the RHS of the original inequality, which preserves the inequality. the second follows by subtracting a strictly positive term from the RHS which preserves the inequality and indeed makes it strict.

Comment: Oh... I'm dumb.  Thanks.

Comment: nah, you just weren't thinking in the right direction. What would be dumb is if you accepted this as fact just because your book said so without understanding why it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we have established $$(1+x)^n \ge 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$ we also have 
$$1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2 > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$ and $$1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2 \ge 1+nx$$ (Where we have strict inequality when $x > 0$). Thus the *weaker* inequalities follow:
$$(1+x)^n \ge 1 + nx$$
$$(1+x)^n \gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2$$ with strict inequality when $x > 0$.